# Out of Date refrigerated Cook Meat Vacuumed sealed

Tags: food-safety

If I have a Pre-Cooked Prime Rib in my refrigerator for 80 days that was below 40°F  that has never opened up, can I re-cook this product meeting time and temperature and still have a safe product to enjoy without any worries?

Comment: Short answer, though: No, that would be intensely unsafe.

Comment: Almost certainly it would smell/taste so rotten that you would immediately know it's bad and wouldn't even *want* to eat it.